# Angular 4 -> Push Objects to an Array

Tags: arrays, angular, blackjack

I'm having an issue with pushing a new object to an existing array.

**What I am trying to do ->**
I am trying to push a new card drawn into the existing array/object

**app.component.ts**

```
     @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
      })
      export class AppComponent {
      title = 'app';
      deck: any;
      cards = [];
      hand = 0;
      cardCount: number;

      constructor(private _data: DataService){
        console.log("Data Service ready to query api");

      };


      newDeck(){
            this._data.newDeck().subscribe(res => this.deck = res.json());

      }

      deal(cardCount){
          this._data.deal(cardCount, this.deck.deck_id).subscribe(response => this.cards = response.json());

          if(this.cards){

            this.cards.push(this.cards);

          }
      }
```

**app.component.html**

```
    <h1>New Game</h1>
    <button (click)="newDeck()">Start</button>

    <p>{{ deck.remaining }} cards left!</p>

    <div>
      <h2>Your Hand</h2>
        <button (click)="deal(2)">Deal</button> <button (click)="deal(1)">Hit</button>
        <img width="150" src="{{cards.cards[0].image}}">
        <img width="150" src="{{cards.cards[1].image}}">
        <img width="150" src="{{cards.cards[2].image}}">
        <img width="150" src="{{cards.cards[3].image}}">
    </div>

    <!-- <div *ngFor="let card of cards">

        <img src="{{card.cards.image}}" width="150px" style="padding: 50px; margin: 10px;">

    </div> -->
```

Yes - My `*ngFor` is broken because it doesn't seem to believe the cards are stored in an array.

> ERROR -> Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Nevertheless, I attached a screenshot of what is happening. I can select the Deal button, but when I click `Hit`, the counter does only pull 1 card but it is not stored in the array. Instead, it acts as a new object and displays as `card.cards[0].image` instead of `card.cards[2].image`, since there are already 2 objects in the array after clicking the deal button.

Any ideas on how to push the new cards to into the cards array? [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D57ZV.png)

It may help to see how the cards are received when called ->

```
                {
                  "remaining": 50,
                  "deck_id": "1omsivg9l9cu",
                  "success": true,
                  "cards": [
                      {
                          "image": "http://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/KS.png",
                          "images": {
                              "svg": "http://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/KS.svg",
                              "png": "http://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/KS.png"
                          },
                          "suit": "SPADES",
                          "value": "KING",
                          "code": "KS"
                      },
                      {
                          "image": "http://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/AH.png",
                          "images": {
                              "svg": "http://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/AH.svg",
                              "png": "http://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/AH.png"
                          },
                          "suit": "HEARTS",
                          "value": "ACE",
                          "code": "AH"
                      }
                  ]
              }
```

Comment: This row looks a little tricky: `this.cards.push(this.cards);`

Comment: Should this row be changed?

Comment: Can't really say, I have no idea, what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: watch your source `src="{{card.cards.image}}"` you are having `cards` which is a array and not a plain object. Update the post with the sample json object

Comment: @CommercialSuicide I'm trying to push new cards pulled with "hit" button. The hit button makes the cardCount =1, then draws 1 card. Right now, it draws a card as it's own individual object - I want to store it with the other cards in a single array.

Comment: @Aravind should be src="{{card.cards[0].image}}"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use the `card.cards` object in your `ngFor`

```
<span *ngFor="let item of data.cards">
      <img src="{{item.image}}" width="150px" style="padding: 50px; margin: 10px;">

</span>
```

Comment: Dude omg you are amazing thank you! Not I just need to learn to store the new card in the array with the other cards. Thank you so much

Comment: I'm hesitant to mark answer as I am having another huge issue

Comment: Hey @Aravind based on the above scripts, any ideas on how to push new cards to the cards array?

Comment: I didnt understand your question can you please elaborate?

Comment: I'm requesting assistance on pushing new cards to the cards array in app.component.ts.

Comment: are you available in teamviewer?